# VMware Player Ubuntu display is duplicating (triplicating) the monitor

Tags: ubuntu, display, vmware-player

I am using VMware Player 6.0.2 and I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  When I recently upgraded my VMware Player, I now have duplicate/triplicate (and sometimes even more) displays going on at the same time.

I am not using multiple workspaces, this is the same workspace being repeated multiple times. (If I open a  file, it is shown multiple times, but only one copy exists. Open a folder, it is shown multiple times. Etc.)

I have tried to adjust the display settings within Ubuntu.  it thinks i have a laptop set at 811 X 968.  Both of my dual monitors are 1920 X 1080.

I have played with the `Edit virtual machine settings` and adjusted the display, but that has made it worse, not better.  (Unchecked `accelerate 3d graphics`, adjusted the `specify monitor settings` to my settings, instead of `auto-detect`, etc.)

What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping this newbie out.  I will be working on the answer provided by BOOMER as soon as I can.  (Extra thanks to HoplessNoob for editing my question to be readable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced some similar issues:

- Win7 64Bit Host OS
- VMWware Player version 5 and 6
- Ubunutu 12.04 LTS.

I reverted to a previous linux install on boot one revision back and seemed to fix the problem for me.

> Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-64-generic-pae (Has the issue)
>
> Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-61-generic-pae (Fixed the issue for me)

Now to get the default boot to use 61 instead of 64 it seems on reboot the problem returns.

Hope this helps.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm experiencing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2poq.png

[image]

---

**Edit** Fixed it permanently for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove 3.2.0-64
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

- https://askubuntu.com/a/482761/182016

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but was running 3.2.0-67
Search the system log for 3.2.0 to see what version you are actually running.
   In gnome, that's System Log Viewer, SYSLOG
   Look in the Filters: menu and ADD regular expression is 3.2.0
   Choose highlight, not hide.
   Go back into the filters menu and tick your new filter, then show matches only.

Follow the steps in the ticked answer but substitute the highest number you find (I had 3.2.0-67).

Repeat until the problem goes away.

I had to remove 3.2.0-67 and 3.2.0-65

Comment: A more simplistic approach from CLI: `uname -a`